# Replace all occurances of / character into a String

Tags: javascript

```
var dateNow = new Date().toLocaleDateString() ;
dateNow.replace(/\//g , "-");
```

I would like to replace all occurances of "/" character by "-" into my dateNow String.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You did it correctly, except for the reassignment. 

But do it like this:


    `var dateNow = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g , "-");`

Answer (score 2):

`replace()` does not do the changes in-place. You have to assign the returned value to something:

```
var dateNow = new Date().toLocaleDateString() ;
dateNow = dateNow.replace(/\//g , "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

You've done it, except `.replace` *returns* the new string, it does not change it in place

```
var result = dateNow.replace(/\//g , "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

That does, but you need to assign it to `dateNow`:

```
dateNow = dateNow.replace(/\//g , "-");
```